# How to assign a list within list in a for loop in R

Tags: r, list, indexing

I am trying to figure out why, methodologically, my code below is not working.

`formatted_data` is a list containing 20 different data frames with various columns. `ff_demog_table` is a function that formats the data frames within `formatted_data`. Finally, `formatted_tables` should be a list saving the different formatted data frames.

I want to iterate over each data frame in the `formatted_data` list, and then iterate over each column within each data frame. It seems like I am not able to directly assign `formatted_tables` as `[[i]][[j]]` but it will display the last formatted column if I use just `formatted_tables[[i]]`.

For example, if I try to run the code below, the subscript is out of bounds. Why?

```r
a <- list()
a[[1]][[1]] <- 7
```

But, if I ran the code below it will work.

```r
b <- list()
b[[1]] <- 7
b[[1]][[1]] <- 8
```

I am not able to share the data, but a simple reproducible example would be merely two data frames with multiple columns saved in a list where the columns are made up of factors.

```r
for (i in seq_along(formatted_data)) {
  
  for (j in 1:ncol(formatted_data[[i]])) {
    
    formatted_tables[[i]][[j]] <- ff_demog_table(formatted_data[[i]], colnames(formatted_data[[i]][j]))
    
  }
  
}
```

In short, any help on understanding R's list indexing would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Just do `lapply(formated_data, function(dat) data.frame(Map(ff_demog_table, dat, names(dat))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may initialize the `list` with a specific `length`.  In the below code, it is a `list` of length 1 instead of the 0 length `list` with `list()`

```
a <- vector('list', 1)
a[[1]][[1]] <- 7
```

---

Or if we want to construct from `length` 0 list, wrap with `list` on the rhs of `<-`

```
a <- list()
a[1] <- list(list(7))
```

-output structure

```
> str(a)
List of 1
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num 7
```